# Multiple groupBy with date in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

How can I achieve this output (image below).

[image]

This is my `Types Table`.

[image]

and this is my `Accounts Table`.

[image]

This is my `Type Model`.

```
public function accounts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Accounts');
}
```

This is my `Account Model`.

```
public function type()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Type', 'type_id');
}
```

What I want to do is, I want to group the `accounts table` by `types` and by `month`, and then I want to add all `amount` on each `month`, and display to the table using `DataTables`.

I tried this code, but it's not giving the expected output.

```
$query = Accounts::with('type')->whereYear('created_at', $selectedYear)->select('type_id',
    DB::raw('type_id as type_id'), 
    DB::raw('sum(amount) as total_amount'),
    DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%m') as months")
)->groupBy('months')->get();
```

I'm still stuck on this part,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Laravel documentations says that you can pass multiple parameters in groupBy method.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

```
$query = Accounts::with('type')->whereYear('created_at', $selectedYear)->select('type_id',
    DB::raw('type_id as type_id'), 
    DB::raw('sum(amount) as total_amount'),
    DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%m') as months")
)->groupBy('type_id', 'months')->get();
```

Comment: I already did this groupBy type_id is not working, only months. Thanks